# How far can two symmetric matrices be from being non-commuting (in a suitable norm)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

In some work I've been doing, I've come across a problem which involves a family of symmetric matrices $A_k\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ for $1\le k\le m$. The problem is very well-behaved when $A_k$ pair-wise commute, but things become harder if the $A_k$ are very far from commuting. What I would like to do, then, is to maximize
$$
 \| [A,B]\|_{HS}^2,\quad\hbox{ subject to } \|A\|_{HS},\|B\|_{HS}\le1
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{HS}$ denotes the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, $\|A\|_{HS}^2=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}^2=\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)$.

I have found that for any maximal pair $(A,B)$, we must have that 
$$
\operatorname{tr}ACBB-\operatorname{tr}CBAB=\lambda\operatorname{tr}CA,
\quad
\operatorname{tr}AACB-\operatorname{tr}ABCA=\eta\operatorname{tr}CB
$$
for all $C\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, and $\lambda,\eta\ge0$ (this is equivalent to $(A,B)$ being a local maximum). This is equivalent to the condition that
$$
ABB-BAB=\lambda A,\quad
BAA-ABA=\eta B.
$$
But can this condition be reduced further? I'm really more interested in finding the maximum, than finding which $A,B$ attain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, we can choose a basis to make it diagonal. Reordering the
basis if necessary, we can make the diagonal entries $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ of $A$ ascending (i.e. $\lambda_1 \le \cdots \le \lambda_n$).

Let $B = (b_{ij})$, we have $( AB - BA)_{ij} =  b_{ij}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)$. This leads to

$$\| [A, B] \|_{HS}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}^2 (\lambda_i - 
\lambda_j)^2
\le \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}^2 (\lambda_n - \lambda_1)^2
= \|B\|^2_{HS}(\lambda_n - \lambda_1)^2
\le (\lambda_n - \lambda_1)^2
$$

Since $\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 + \cdots \lambda_n^2 = \|A\|^2_{HS} \le 1$, we have

$$(\lambda_n - \lambda_1)^2 \le (\lambda_n - \lambda_1)^2 + (\lambda_n + \lambda_1)^2 = 2(\lambda_n^2 + \lambda_1^2) \le 2\tag{*1}$$

From this, we can conclude

$$\|[A,B]\|_{HS} \le 2\quad\text{ for symmetric }\;\; A, B \;\;\text{ whenever }\;\;
\| A \|_{HS}, \| B \|_{HS} \le 1\tag{*2}$$

Notice in $(*1)$, the equality is achieved when $$\lambda_1 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \lambda_2 = \cdots = \lambda_{n-1} = 0, \lambda_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

With this as a hint, we find

$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 &-1 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is an example where the upper bound $2$ in $(*2)$ is achieved.

Comment: That should be $\| [A,B]\|^2_{HS} \le 2$, I think.

Comment: @RobertIsrael typos fixed. thanks.